# Using html2text with html utf8

Tags: python

I have problem with html2text

```
input = "<h1 itemprop="name">B&#242; 33 M&#243;n</h1>"
```

I use

```
from stripogram import html2text
print html2text(input)
print html2text(input.decode('utf8'))
```

And my result

```
B 33 Mn
```

Result I need

```
Bò 33 món
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `html2text(input)` is Unicode. To print it with `print`, you need to get it back down to 8-bits per character by converting it to UTF-8:

```
from stripogram import html2text
print html2text(input).encode('utf-8')
```

which will print

`# Bò 33 Món`